# Send byte[] to Applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet, base64

I have a Java Web application using Struts 1.3, which makes communication with an Applet for printing a report.
This report is made by web application without problems, however, I am unable to send to the Applet.

I searched here and others forums, and a solution that apparently worked with most was the conversion of byte[] using Base64. I tried but didn't work for me. For some reason, when the applet attempts to decode, it can't. Does not generate any error, it just does not come out of the line where is the decode, it's like was went into an infinite loop.

The following code generates the Base64:

```
try {
    byte[] report = PrinterFacade.generateReport();
    [...]

    response.getWriter().write(Base64.encodeBase64String(report));
} catch (Exception e) {
    [...]
    throw e;
}
```

This is the JavaScript code that calls the Applet:

```
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST"
        url: "${printing}"
        success: function(data) {
            document.applet.print(data);
        },
        [...]
    });
```

This is the code Applet:

```
public void print(String report) throws Exception {
    try {
        byte[] pdf = Base64.decodeBase64(report);

        [...]
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I checked and the String report comes populated with the right data in the Applet side.

Does anyone know what can it be?

Comment: Are you really sure the string you're getting in print is the one you sent? You could try decoding it via maybe an online decoder like https://www.base64decode.org/ to be sure the data is correct.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I used the online decoder to check and the is the same result =/